# Почему так отображаются данные?

Tags: c#, сокет

Здравствуй ХешКод,  решил сделать программу которая будет через Сокеты передавать данные, так вот почему когда данные передаются с клиента в сервер, после этой строчки делается пропуск 4-х строк?

```
Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
sck.Connect("127.0.0.1", 2000);

while (true) {
    byte[]buffer = new byte[255];

    int num = sck.Receive(buffer);

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
}

Console.Read();
```

Comment: А где эти четыре пропущенные строки? Покажите рукоделие.

Comment: Зачем сразу минусовать, я задал вопрос с телефона т.к небыло инета на компе, код только щяс смог допечатать(долго переписывать).

Comment: После какой именно строчки?

Comment: Да, есть с сокетами какая-то проблема с верностью данных. И растёт она вроде от того что TCP гарантирует только доставку пакета данных, но не порядок. Года три назад разбирался, но так и не разобрался, интересен ответ тоже.

Comment: @Чад, ***не дезинформируйте читателей !*** 

**TCP гарантирует** доставку, порядок и достоверность передаваемых данных.

Я не знаю C#, могу только предположить, что **num** из отправленных данных (м.б. к моменту возврата из Receive() не все отправленные и не знаю, как в C# это связано с 255) помещены в buffer. 

--

Скажем в Си num = recv(sock,buffer,255,0) поместит по адресу buffer максимум 255 байт (может меньше), **но не запишет** никакого нуля,  завершающего в Си строки. 

После recv() можно написать:

    if (num >= 0) buffer[num] = 0;

безусловно это зависит от логики задачи.

Comment: Из википедии:

> **Обнаружение ошибок при передаче данных** Хотя протокол осуществляет
> проверку контрольной суммы по каждому
> сегменту, используемый алгоритм
> считается слабым [1]. Так в 2008 году
> не обнаруженная сетевыми средствами
> ошибка в передаче одного бита, привела
> к остановке серверов системы Amazon
> Web Services [2]. В общем случае
> распределенным сетевым приложениям
> рекомендуется использовать
> дополнительные программные средства
> для гарантирования целостности
> передаваемой информации[3].

Comment: @Чад, это конечно интересно, но к данному случаю (и практически ко всем другим) отношения не имеет.

IMHO, то с чем Вы 3 года разбирались тоже не связано с "ненадежностью" TCP.

Comment: Вполне вероятно. Но там явно проблема была с сокетной передачей (может я upd использовал) - проблема возникала при достаточно специфичных условиях сети (большая загруженость при езернете и слабый сигнал при файвае). При этом в рамках дебага или не загруженной сети проблем не возникало. Я лишь хотел отетить что такая проблема вероятна. Но скорее всего не в данном случае.

Comment: Действительно, UDP  **не гарантирует** ни порядок доставки пакетов, ни то, что пакеты не будут потеряны. Контроль целостности пакета осуществляется.

Обычно (особенно в локалке) пакеты приходят в порядке отправления. Потери пакетов обычно происходят при переполнении очереди к порту приемника (сокету) в ядре ОС. Т.е. если производительность принимающего компьютера недостаточна.

Answer (score 1):

Angus123, а в кокой кодировке сервер посылает данные? поскольку если данные посылаются в кодировке UTF-8 то на каждый символ потребуется 2 байта и тогда будет несоответствие размеров буферов, так что попробуйте взять буфер побольше

Comment: Encoding.Default - вот в такой)

Comment: @Angus123, Вы конкретно выводимые (и передаваемые с севера тоже хорошо бы) данные приведите. Ну, вроде скриншота, или опишите подробно что и где Вы видите. 

А то мы здесь **никаких** строчек не видим, что за сервер на порту 2000 localhost-а и что он Вам передает не знаем.

Comment: `Encoding.Default` — это очень плохо. Потому что `Encoding.Default` на каждой машине свой: если стоит русская Windows, это CP1251, а если немецкая, то европейская локаль и т. д.